# Divide Capistrano Tag

Tags: discussion, tags, version-tags

Capistrano 3 has been released and is radically different from Capistrano V2. I suggest taking all Capistrano tags and moving them to capistrano2, creating a new Capistrano3 tag and making capistrano a synonym of capistrano3.

I don't have the rep to make these moves. Guess I am asking for a sponsor?

Answer (score 4):

Retagging all the older questions is *not required*. There might be a possibility that the problem OP is facing is not version specific. [Version specific tags](/q/85358/212576) should be avoided as much as possible so that users can subscribe to a single tag for their field of expertise.

As for creating a new version-specific tag for Capistrano v3, you can edit your post with the link to a question which is based on the newer version and any user with [the create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) privilege would create it.